# MATLAB: How to make a list of words in matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matlab

Cross-posted from stackoverflow, where there seemed to be no interest:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329233/matlab-how-make-a-list-of-words-in-matrices

Given two n by n invertible matrices A and B, I'd like to create a list of all non-trivial words (multiplied out) of bounded length N in A,B, and their inverses. How would I do this in matlab?

To clarify, a word is a sequence of A,B,A^-1,B^-1 in any order, and non-trivial means that we don't have a subsequence like A,A^-1 or B^-1,B and we ignore the empty sequence. 'Multiplied out' means that I want to evaluate a sequence like A,B,A^-1 as A*B*A^-1, to get a matrix.

Example: The list of (multiplied out) non-trivial words of length at most 2 is

A,B,A^-1,B^-1,A*A,A*B,A*B^-1, B*A,B*A^-1,B*B

Comment: Is it really required to have anything to do with matlab? It would seem all you need is the collection of lists of length at most $n$ for which there are no substrings of length $2$ which are one of $a,b$ followed/preceeded by its inverse. A count of how many might be easy via combinatorics. A recursive way to generate them might be what you need...

Comment: Your list of length at most 2 is missing the length two cases starting with either $A^{-1}$ or $B^{-1}.$ There are 4 choices for the first term and then three after that, so there should be 4*3=12 length two strings.

Answer (score 1):

The non-trivial words of length 1 are $$
  \mathcal{W}_1 =\left\{A,B,A^{-1},B^{-1}\right\} \text{.}
$$
If $\mathcal{W}_n$ is the set of non-trivial words $\omega = \omega_1\ldots\omega_n$ of length $n$, then the set of non-trivial words of length $n+1$ is\begin{eqnarray}
  \mathcal{W}_{n+1}
  &=& \left\{\omega A \,:\, \omega \in \mathcal{W_n}, \omega_n \neq A^{-1}\right\} \\
  &\cup& \left\{\omega B \,:\, \omega \in \mathcal{W_n}, \omega_n \neq B^{-1}\right\} \\
  &\cup& \left\{\omega A^{-1} \,:\, \omega \in \mathcal{W_n}, \omega_n \neq A\right\} \\
  &\cup& \left\{\omega B^{-1} \,:\, \omega \in \mathcal{W_n}, \omega_n \neq B\right\}
  \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}

From that it follows that the total number of non-trivial words in of length $n+1$ is $$
  \left|\mathcal{W}_{n+1}\right| = 4\left(\frac{3}{4}\left|\mathcal{W}_{n}\right|\right)
  = 3\left|\mathcal{W}_{n}\right| = 3^{n}\left|\mathcal{W}_{1}\right| = 4\cdot 3^n \text{.}
$$

Using this, it should be pretty straight-forward to write a recursive MATLAB procedure that produces $\mathcal{W}_n$.